# citation using mendeley using gedit

Tags: gedit, citations, mendeley

I am using Mendeley as my reference manager, and gedit as document editor. I saved my references to a .bib file, then used the command \cite{ReferenceName}. It does not complain when I compile, but the pdf only shows [?]. Should I have imported any package in the beginning for this to work? Or is it a problem with gedit, and I should use a different text editor like vim.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For help with BibTeX and LaTeX a better place to ask is https://tex.stackexchange.com/